# Does the tag info need updated or am I misunderstanding?

Tags: discussion, tags

The current [technical-issues](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-issues) tag info reads,
"Technical support is for questions regarding help with technical problems such as installing or running a game. It is important to note system settings with these sort of questions."

Correct me if I am wrong but shouldn't it read something more like,
"Technical support for questions regarding technical problems like, but not limited to installing or running a game. It is important to note system settings with these sort of questions."

As the current text makes it sound like it is only for installing or game running issues. Does the tag not also include issues inside the game itself? Such as certain parts of the game not working, but as a whole the game works fine. (Sorry if that is not the clearest, having trouble getting this point across).

Comment: Technical issues is one of those tags we use rather inconsistently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't read the current text like that at all. "Such as" does not, in my mind, create the exclusivity in topics you seem to be attributing to it. Technical problems relating to installing or running a game are just two of the most common examples of things that fall under the purview of the [technical-issues](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-issues) tag.

The [Grammarly Handbook](http://www.grammarly.com/handbook/punctuation/comma/38/such-as-comma/), and [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/such_as) note the use of "such as" to provide examples, where the example(s) listed are not the only possible things contained within a given set. [Grammar Girl](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/like-versus-such-as) also has an entry on "such as" comparing it to the use of "like". Ultimately the two are very similar, and often interchangeable.

Your proposed change does little to alter the meaning of the phrasing beyond substituting "like" in place of "such as", giving it a slightly less formal sound.

And as 3ventic points out, issues occurring inside the game can be considered an issue running the game.

Comment: +1 I agree "such as" does not set the scope of the tag.  However changing "such as" to "like, but not limited to" would certainly open up the scope of the tag.  Personally I support the change given the at times avaricious desire by some Stack Exchange enthusiasts to close every question that doesn't fit perfectly into their mental definition of a SE site.

Comment: @Lumberjack If something does not quite fit the tag, I would only expect there to be a potential edit war over the inclusion of the tag. If the question that did/didn't use the tag was closed, there are likely issues beyond the phrasing of the technical issues tag that are causing it to be closed.

Comment: what I imagine instead is a question being closed as "Off Topic" because its not a "Technical issue" or an "In game issue" because the game installs/runs fine.  Trying to play South Park with a $10 keyboard is a fine example.

Answer (score 0):

Issues in the game are not technical issues. They do not change based on how you installed the game or how you're running it. If they do, you have an issue running or installing the game. Practically all questions on Arqade are either technical issues or issues in a game, so tagging both with the same tag wouldn't make much sense.

> Such as certain parts of the game not working, but as a whole the game works fine.

The whole game doesn't work fine if parts of it don't work fine. It's an issue running the game or an unexpected game mechanic you're unaware of.

Answer (score -4):

In my opinion, yes, your clarification is appropriate.  If I had the power to do so, I would update the wording of the tag.

I can think of a number of technical issues that are not directly related to installing or running the game.  For example, if you installed  the Tekkit mod on your Minecraft server, which in turn caused all of your anvils to disappear.  In this case, the game might "run" just fine, but some functionality is broken or unavailable due to a technical issue.

Maybe the game installs and runs, but later crashes to desktop when the stars align.  Maybe chunks won't load.  Maybe certain keyboards can't support the rapid level of key-presses needed to save Randy from the Alien's probe.

In summary, there are myriad technical issues not directly related to installing or running a game.

Comment: I'm sorry you don't find my answer useful.

Comment: The meaning of votes up/down in meta often different things than on the main site. A downvote on a meta answer generally indicates disagreement with the point being made rather than an indication of usefulness. All opinions (that aren't offensive or otherwise actionable) are useful.